# Does install hook execute everytime juju deploy is called

Tags: 14.04, juju, automation

I might be wrong in understanding the hooks lifecycle but what I've understood from the following link is that everytime juju deploy somecharm is called juju looks for the hook files that are going to be executed in that particular scenario i.e install,config-changed,start etc.

https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.24/authors-charm-hooks

My question is that whenever "juju deploy somecharm" is called will juju execute install hook everytime?

Answer (score 3):

The "install" hook is run whenever a new *unit* of a *service* is added. When you deploy a charm, you're creating a service and a unit (or more than one unit by specifying the "-n" flag).

For example, if you do:
    juju deploy mysql
you will have a mysql service, and a single unit of the service. That unit will run its install hook when it's finished initialising.

If you then do:
    juju add-unit mysql
you will have two mysql units; the new unit will run its install hook when it's finished initialising.

Comment: Thanks alot! I was confused in this concept because read so many articles regarding juju lifecycle. Got it !